# Where to find the Base module of LibreOffice that has no row limit?

Tags: rows, libreoffice-base

I have a file that has ten million rows. I want to open it using OpenOffice Calc but OpenOffice Calc 3.3.3 has a limit of around one million rows.

If you [**follow this link**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8631/upper-limit-to-number-of-rows-in-calc/), the answer mentioned that the Base module of LibreOffice has **NO ROW LIMIT**.

Comment: Libreoffice [Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) is a [Database Management System](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Database_1) like Access is for Microsoft Office.

Comment: What kind of file is it -- .ods, .xlsx, or .csv perhaps?  LibreOffice Base uses .odb files and can read other types of database files such as dBASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibreOffice Base can use `Text` files as the data source.  Documentation is here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Text_File_Connection.

To test this, the following python script produces a text file with ten million rows.

```py
with open("datasource.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("id,name\n")
    TEN_MILLION = 10000000
    for id_number in range(TEN_MILLION):
        f.write("%d,abc\n" % id_number)
```

Open Base by going to File -> New -> Database in the LibreOffice menu.  Then connect to an existing database.

[image: connect to Text]

Now, the "datasource" table can be viewed by opening it.

[image: datasource table]

Comment: Thanks for your time and help